# Call a controller's action in an onEventSelect?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, schedule

I've tried using the primefaces' schedule component, and I can navigate when an event is clicked by using this:

XHTML:

```
<p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{myControllerBean.eventModel}">
    <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{pmyControllerBean.onEventSelect}"/>
</p:schedule>
```

Java:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.ConfigurableNavigationHandler;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultScheduleEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.LazyScheduleModel;
import org.primefaces.model.ScheduleModel;

public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    ConfigurableNavigationHandler cnh =
        (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)FacesContext.
            getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

    cnh.performNavigation("myPage?faces-redirect=true");
}
```

My problem is that *myPage* should actually be returned by a method called from another controller bean, which takes a parameter (think details page for an entity):

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class EntityDetails {
    private MyEntity entity;

    public String getDetail(MyEntity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
        return "myPage";
    }
}
```

I also know how to retrieve the MyEntity object from the event (I've extended DefaultScheduleEvent to contain it) in onEventSelect, so it looks like this at this point:

```
public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    ConfigurableNavigationHandler cnh =
        (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)FacesContext.
            getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();

    MyEntity entity = ((MyEntityEvent)selectEvent.getObject()).getEntity()

    cnh.performNavigation("MyPage?faces-redirect=true");
}
```

My question is: how can I call and redirect to EntityDetail.getDetails(entity) in onEventSelect?

**Update:** So ok, you can use the method directly. But I now have another problem: if I keep the "?faces-redirect=true", my detail page shows no data from my entity at all. If I remove it, I get the correct data, but the next navigation (any navigation) leads to the detail page again, but this time with no data again.

```
@Inject EntityDetails entityDetail;
...
cnh.performNavigation(entityDetails.getDetail(entity) + "?faces-redirect=true"); //no data in the page
cnh.performNavigation(entityDetails.getDetail(entity)); //data present, but the next navigation leads to the details page with no data
```

Comment: Your @RequestScoped is jsf annotation or CDI? You can just paste the import statement if that is unknown.

Comment: What is wrong with just calling it? I fail to see the problem. It is a static call and no need for it to be managed bean.

Comment: @Kukeltje I am guessing OP is confused on use of \\@\\Inject or \\@\\ManagedProperty?

Comment: Could indeed be the case. But why injection if you pass it in an event? On the other hand OP extended some code there. Sounds like an xy problem

Comment: And you can use backticks around the `@Inject`

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Like mentioned above, use injection. Read about these concepts in basic in jsf/cdi tutorials.

Comment: Forgot to put it, but I do inject EntityDetails (edited).

Comment: after update: this goes in new question. But before that do read a lot about faces-redirect and bean scope